# Cannot monitor impala queries on Cloudera Manager

Tags: monitoring, cloudera, impala, cloudera-manager

I got installed a new cloudera cluster with versions CM-6.3.1 and CDH-6.3.2 and now facing a problem never had with previous cloudera distributions,

Cloudera Management Services (including Cloudera Service Monitor), Impala (Sentry Enabled), and all other related processes are working fine. Individual users are able to authenticate with LDAP and can query tables to which they are authorized.

The problem is, the queries sent and executed to impala daemons **do not appear in the Impala Queries tab** in Cloudera Manager, i checked the things discussed in the link below.

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Empty-Impala-queries-in-Cloudera-Manager/td-p/79812

No troubles in either `/var/log/cloudera-scm-firehose/mgmt-cmf-mgmt-SERVICEMONITOR-hostname.log.out` or `var/log/cloudera-scm-server/cloudera-scm-server.log`logs.

There is enough disk space in the **Service Monitor Storage Directory**.

And tried to set to different sizes from 1GB to 3GB **Impala Storage** (`firehose_impala_storage_bytes`)

Everything seems fine, yet there are no queries in the Cloudera Manager Web-UI. What might be the cause of this situation?

Any help would be highly appreciated,

Thanks.